# curl does not return reponse data even CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set to true in php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the response data from a web page . I have set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true, however the response only returns false. 
I am wondering what is wrong with my link. But if I put the link in browser, it works. The following is my code:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_POST => FALSE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Does the link start with HTTPS? Also have you included curl_init() before the code above?

Comment: A return value `false` indicates, that the request has failed. Obviously in such case you won't get any payload data returned. So your real question is: why does that request fail?

Comment: like arkascha said, check if curl_exec($ch) is false. If it is, you can print the error message with curl_error($ch) and the error code with curl_errno($ch). Post the message and the code for further help

Comment: I have try two link, when I use 
$ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com.hk') it is ok
However, if I use 
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com.hk')
it returns false
So, is that something need to do with the https protocol?